# merge unknown number of sub-arrays in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
arr = [ [[x,x],[x,x]], [[x,x],[x,x],[x,x]], [[x,x]] ]
```

and I want to turn it into an array like this:

```
arr = [  [x,x],[x,x] ,  [x,x],[x,x],[x,x],   [x,x]  ]
```

so I have tried this:

```
for (var i=1; i< arr.length; i++){ arr[0].concat(arr[i]); }
```

but it does not work. How can I 'merge' this intermediate level of array?

Comment: How does that "not work"?  What output does it give?  Does it give any errors?  Why are you starting with `var i = 1`?

Comment: Starting with i=1 because i=0 would be arr[0] to which I want to add the other sub-arrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With ES6 you can use [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with `concat()`

```js
var arr = [ [['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x'],['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x']] ]

var merged = [].concat(...arr)
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged))
```

For older versions of ecmascript the same can be done using `concat()` and `apply()`.

```js
var arr = [ [['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x'],['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x']] ]

var merged = [].concat.apply([], arr)
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged))
```

Comment: Great! Just the kind of efficient code and new thing to learn I was looking for. What does dot dot dot (...) mean?

Comment: It's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) does.

```
var arr = [ [['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x'],['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x']] ]

var merged = arr.flat()
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged))

[["x","x"],["x","x"],["x","x"],["x","x"],["x","x"],["x","x"]]
```

﻿

Answer (score 1):

The [`array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) doesn't change the array you call it on, but rather returns a *new* array - a new array you are ignoring.

You should create a *result* array and then append everything to that, instead of trying to modify `arr`.

```
var arr = [ [['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x'],['x','x'],['x','x']], [['x','x']] ];
var new_arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    new_arr = new_arr.concat(arr[i]);
}
```